# ContainerView Inside ScrollView don't scroll in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, containers

I have example project on GitHub you can see on -> 
https://github.com/LetSwiftDev/ContainerViewInsideScroll/tree/master

I have two, view controller, one is normal view controller named `oneViewController` second is `twoViewController` inside have `UIScrollView` and when I clicked `OPEN TWO` button going to `twoViewController` inside `ContainerView` but;

> My twoViewController have different height size like 1500 and inside  have scrollview and don't scroll to bottom? I didn't see middle side, bottom side labels.

How can I fix it?
Any idea?

Also my `centerViewController` codes under below. I'm controlling to past view controllers with `centerViewController`

```
import UIKit

open class centerViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate weak var viewController : UIViewController!
    fileprivate var containerViewObjects = Dictionary<String,UIViewController>()

    open var currentViewController : UIViewController{
        get {
            return self.viewController

        }
    }


    fileprivate var segueIdentifier : String!

    @IBInspectable internal var startUp : String!


    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



    }
    open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let identifier = startUp{
            segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent(identifier)
        }
    }
    override open func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func segueIdentifierReceivedFromParent(_ identifier: String){

        self.segueIdentifier = identifier
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.segueIdentifier, sender: nil)

    }




    override open func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == segueIdentifier{

            if viewController != nil{


                viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
                viewController = nil

            }
            if ((self.containerViewObjects[self.segueIdentifier] == nil)){
                viewController = segue.destination
                self.containerViewObjects[self.segueIdentifier] = viewController

            }else{
                for (key, value) in self.containerViewObjects{

                    if key == self.segueIdentifier{

                        viewController = value


                    }

                }


            }

            self.addChildViewController(viewController)
            viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width,height: self.view.frame.height)
            self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
            viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: This github link is your demo?

Comment: @JitendraModi yeah all codes there

Comment: @JitendraModi if you download and click run after click open two button and you can see there don't scroll , scroll view to bottom side , I don't see

Comment: Yeah, i am just running your demo. I am solving it.

Comment: @JitendraModi good luck ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143955/discussion-between-jitendra-modi-and-swiftdeveloper).

Answer (score 3):

Here is your demo with solution. You can download it from here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvrjd0gp06xe5nw/ContainerViewInsideScroll-master%202.zip?dl=0

The thing is You have to learn autolayout for Scrollview.

I am just giving tips for the given constraint to scrollview.

First take scrollview and fit to the screen and give constraint as follows

[image]

Now take a view inside scrollview and fit to scrollview and give constraint like

[image: image2]

Still its giving error of constraint. So now, give equal width of view to scrollview

[image: image3]

and now you can take as many control as you want and give constraints as normal as we give to other controls.

Hope you understand well. 
Enjoy Coding.

Comment: dude i did everything with your answer but don't worked in my project can you help me ?

Comment: you changed else somethings ?

Comment: yeah, I changed constraints in your project

Comment: if you want video then I will send you.

Comment: ty but another example I try working but in my project doesn't work you changed else in project ? or have Skype ?

Comment: not accessible, I am on my work. So I can send you video. if you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143966/discussion-between-swiftdeveloper-and-jitendra-modi).

Comment: I can talk on skype but only text message not video conversation

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `scrollView` is too long and hidden below the screen and `contentSize` isn't configured properly.

[image]

A lazy solution is to set them properly in code when twoViewController appears.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let width = self.scrollView.frame.width
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(origin: scrollView.frame.origin,
                              size: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(500)))
    // Make sure this height is longer than scrollView.
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(2000))
  }
```

The proper solution (and correct way to implement a scrollview) is to fix scrollable content size ambiguity (auto layout errors in storyboard) like what @Jitendra Modi mentioned.

Comment: Setting the frame helped me. Thank you.